# Why is .remove() not removing the object from array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

In this project, a keyboard-arrow controlled cat walks over mice and causes them to disappear.

[Main.js](https://pastebin.com/gX7Thj5n)

[Index.html](https://pastebin.com/tUiv6m0Q)

[Style.css](https://pastebin.com/ae6wqDyY)

[Screenshot of app in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtSkQ.png)

The mice are successfully disappearing within the browser window, however, when I console log the "mice" array, the mouse objects are not disappearing from the array; there remains 7 objects.
However, I want to alert the user when they've successfully eliminated all of the mice (and eventually add another level). It seems that this code is only removing the HTML div element and not the actual object from the array.

```
if(mice.length === 0){
    console.log("success!")
}
```

Initially I tried the above but it 1. logs to the console on initial render right before the array is populated and 2. doesn't work as I intended since the array length never goes back to 0.

```
function checkCollisions(){
    mice.forEach(mouse => {
        if(collision(mouse.mouse, cat)){
            sound.play()
            mouse.mouse.remove()
            // generateMouse()  //* removed regenerate
            console.log(mice)
        }
    })
}
```

Is `mouse.mouse.remove()` just removing the html div from the browser? I'm not understanding why this is not removing the "mouse" property from the object.
How can I get it to remove the collided mouse from the array?

[Console screenshot after initial render and checkCollisions() executing twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bC2H.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're not doing anything to the array, why should the mouse be removed from it?

Comment: The array is not automatically updated when you change the DOM.

Comment: why not doing `delete object.key;`?

Comment: Don't post images of code

Answer (score -1):

There's no link between the DOM and the array. Removing the div from the DOM won't automatically remove the element from the array.

You shouldn't modify an array while you're iterating over it. You can use `filter()` to create a new array based on the original `mice` array.

```
function checkCollisions() {
  mice = mice.filter(mouse => {
    if (collision(mouse.mouse, cat)) {
      sound.play()
      mouse.mouse.remove()
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  })
}
```